# 500 error when attempting to upload images using pixel and tonic assets module on localhost

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, file-uploads, localhost

I have set up a vhost in mamp `(http://az-cms:8887/)` - and installed expression engine as well as the assets module. I have a directory set up on my local hard drive within the expression engine uploads directory, with all permissions set to read / write. I can successfully upload files via the file manager, but if I attempt to use "assets", I get the attached errors.[image: 500 error on upload]

Anyone know what the problem is? I've looked in the exp_assets_files_folder table of my DB and it's empty, as is the exp_assets_files directory.